# how can i schedule a job at every 20 seconds using whenever gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to run a job at every 20 seconds. I am using whenever gem
but as per its documentation it allows minimum 1 minute of time.

scheduler

```
every 1.minute do
  runner "DailyNotificationChecker.send_notifications"
end
```

job

i thought i can make an infinite loop and use sleep method and make it sleep for 20 seconds. that way this job will run every 20 seconds but what will happen if my cron will it this method again.

```
class DailyNotificationChecker 
    def self.send_notifications
        Rails.logger.info "Triggered NotificationChecker"
        if RUN_SCHEDULER == "true"
          Rails.logger.info "Running Performer"
          notes = Note.unprocessed
          if notes.present?
            notes.each do |note|
              RealtimeNotificationChecker.performer(note.user_id,"note_created")
              note_hash = {}
              note_hash[:note_id] = note.id
              url = URI.parse(PROCESS_NOTE_API_URL)
              resp, data = Net::HTTP.post_form(url, note_hash)
            end
          end
        sleep 20  #=> workaround for to sleep 20 seconds
        end
      end
end
```

Comment: Could you not just use `every 20.seconds do`?

Comment: No. Under the hood, `whenever` creates a `cron` job - which can only be configured by the minute.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways you could solve this:

1. Accept the per-minute granularity limitation `whenever` (i.e. `cron` jobs) have and just run this task once per minute, without a loop.
2. Run your script as a [daemonised](https://github.com/thuehlinger/daemons) service; do not use `whenever` at all. You could use something like `monit` to ensure the script doesn't die silently.
3. Refactor your code, to instead trigger a new background job *upon each `Notification` creation*. Use a tool such as [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) or [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) to handle the workload.

Comment: i have found a work around @tom please suggest if my code have any downside

Answer (score 0):

considering my situations i have worked around the code

```
def self.send_notifications
        expiry_time = Time.now + 59
        while (Time.now < expiry_time)
          Rails.logger.info "Triggered NotificationChecker"
          if RUN_SCHEDULER == "true" || RUN_SCHEDULER == true
            Rails.logger.info "Running Performer"
            Note.uncached do
              notes = Note.unprocessed.uncached
              if notes.present?
                notes.each do |note|
                  RealtimeNotificationChecker.performer(note.user_id,"note_created")
                  note_hash = {}
                  note_hash[:note_id] = note.id
                  url = URI.parse(PROCESS_NOTE_API_URL)
                  resp, data = Net::HTTP.post_form(url, note_hash)
                end
              end
            end
          end
          sleep 20 #seconds
        end
      end
```

i am running a loop that gets expired at every 59 seconds and sleeps 20 seconds within the loop.

Comment: This works, but it's a hack. What's the point in using `whenever` at all, here? You could just trigger it once, and never "expire" it.

Comment: For example, what happens if there's suddenly a huge workload (i.e. thousands of unprocessed `Note`s)? `Whenever` will re-trigger the script **BEFORE** it expires, causing potential duplication and even system crashing.